# I try access via ssh the server

Tags: ssh, digital-ocean

I tried:

```
$ ssh root@157.245.238.190
```

and I receive:

```
Warning: Permanently added '157.245.238.190' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Why does the connection fails, even though I have added the server fingerprint to the `known_hosts` file?

[image: screenshot ssh session]

Answer (score 0):

While known_hosts might be correctly updated, you sill have to register (add) your public key to `~root/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server side.

If not added, an SSH connection would fail with Permission denied (public key)

Also check [how the `sshd_config` is configured on your droplet](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-can-i-disable-ssh-login-for-a-root-user-i-am-the-account-owner).

Note that the [recommended SSH session is using a user, not `root`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-16-04).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer @VonC But.. I'm still get a problem ..I'll say what I done:
I log in a console web by my panel provided for digitalOcean and I can see my public key in authorized_keys after a restart service ssh .. and in my ubuntu I receive :
Permission denied (publickey). .. I think, the problem can be in my pc!

Comment: @CleberCastiglioni You can your "public key in authorized_keys", but with which account? root? See https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/droplets/how-to/add-ssh-keys/to-existing-droplet/. Usually, you don't log in as root.

Comment: @CleberCastiglioni See also https://gist.github.com/jamiewilson/4e1d28f9a200cb34ad59

Comment: @CleberCastiglioni Can you edit your question with that information? That is easier to read than buried in the comments

Comment: @CleberCastiglioni I see id_dsa twice in your output. Is there id_rsa? What is the name of your private key filename.

Comment: the name is : id_rsa

Comment: running debug  $ssh -vvv root@157.245.238.190 
 [image](https://ibb.co/D8dt1h2).

Comment: @CleberCastiglioni When you log on earlier as root on your Droplet, did you see the content of `id_rsa.pub` (the public key) in `~root/.ssh/authorized_keys`?

Comment: yes! I run $ tail .ssh/authorized_keys and I see my key

Comment: @CleberCastiglioni How about https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/droplets/resources/troubleshooting-ssh/connectivity/? (for instance, the droplet firewall rules)